# Find and Copy a file where the location is not fixed in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to find and copy files with pattern `*-chrony-configuration.yaml` from the `machineconfig` directory to `manifests` directory.

The location of the `machineconfig` varies depending on the user

- if the user is *root*, the folder is */root/machineconfig*
- if the user is *non-root*, the folder is */home/machineconfig*

```yaml
- name: Find machineconfig files generated from helpernode
  find:
    paths: "machineconfig/"
    patterns: "*-chrony-configuration.yaml"
  register: machine_file

- name: Copy machineconfig files generated from helpernode
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ workdir }}/manifests"
    remote_src: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ machine_file.files }}"
```

The above code errors out giving

> "msg": "machineconfig/ was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"

Is there a way in ansible where it finds the path of the file and uses that to produce its copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do, if your path is either */root/machineconfig* or */home/machineconfig*, as it seems, is to feed the [`paths`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-paths) parameter with a list, as the documentation propose it.

Given the task:

```yaml
- find:
    paths: 
      - /root/machineconfig
      - /home/machineconfig
    patterns: "*-chrony-configuration.yaml"
  register: machine_file
```

This will list you the files you are looking for and raise a simple warning for folder that does not exists.

---

With the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  gather_subset: 
    - min

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: 
          - /root/machineconfig
          - /home/machineconfig
        patterns: "*-chrony-configuration.yaml"
      register: machine_file

    - debug:
        var: machine_file.files | map(attribute='path')
```

This yields:

```
TASK [find] ****************************************************************
[WARNING]: Skipped '/root/machineconfig' path due to this access issue:
'/root/machineconfig' is not a directory
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  machine_file.files | map(attribute='path'):
  - /home/machineconfig/foobar-chrony-configuration.yaml
```

---

If the `remote_user` of the playbook is the user for which the `machineconfig` folder is created, then you can use the [`ansible_env.HOME`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables) fact in order to get the home directory of that user.

So, that would make your copy task looks like:

```yaml
- name: Find machineconfig files generated from helpernode
  find:
    paths: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/machineconfig/"
    patterns: "*-chrony-configuration.yaml"
  register: machine_file
  become: no
```

<sup>***Please mind:** that you need to gather some minimal facts for this, to work:*</sup>

```yaml
- hosts: foobar
  gather_facts: yes
  gather_subset: 
    - min
```